# Routing Error with Post/Put requests (Passenger Headers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I've run into a weird problem and after a bunch of research can't get any closer. I've got several forms that upload files via Carrierwave. When I upload the information, part of the route gets cut off (I think).

For example, I have a multi-part form submitting to:

> https:/domain/programs/223/add_file as POST

but on submission I get the error

> No route matches [POST] "/223/add_file"

even though what's in my address bar is the complete route. And if submit the complete route as a GET request it works fine. When I run rake routes the route shows up just fine.

Here is a subset of my route:

```
resources :programs do
  match "add_file" => "programs#add_file"
```

If it matters, I'm running Rails 3.2.2 with Passenger on Apache. The problem only happens on this production server, never in development.

Any ideas? I'm stuck on this one as it effects multiple routes and I've tried defining a custom route just for that form with no luck.

**Update:**
When I remove multi-part => true or the file_field_tag from the form it fixes the problem. It's still an issue but seems to be less about routing than about the form with file uploads.

Comment: I found a dirty solution that seems to work. If my actual route is /programs/223/add_file then my form would need to point to /programs/programs/223/add_file. This shouldn't work but does. Go figure.

Comment: you may want to check my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178033/rails-3-2-f-file-field-causes-routing-error

Comment: This worked for me too. Thank you - you are a life saver! Having my entire application fail was not on the agenda for this week. I'll let you know if there are any side effects from the modification.

Comment: If you don't mind I added an answer, so you could accept it as a correct one ;) thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `passenger_extension.rb` in the `lib` folder with this code:

**Passenger 3**

```
module PhusionPassenger
  module Utils

    protected

    NULL = "\0".freeze

    def split_by_null_into_hash(data)
      args = data.split(NULL, -1)
      args.pop
      headers_hash = Hash.new
      args.each_slice(2).to_a.each do |pair|
        headers_hash[pair.first] = pair.last unless headers_hash.keys.include? pair.first
      end
      return headers_hash
    end

  end
end
```

**Passenger 5**

```
module PhusionPassenger
  module Utils

    # Utility functions that can potentially be accelerated by native_support functions.
    module NativeSupportUtils
      extend self

      NULL = "\0".freeze

      class ProcessTimes < Struct.new(:utime, :stime)
      end

      def split_by_null_into_hash(data)
        args = data.split(NULL, -1)
        args.pop
        headers_hash = Hash.new
        args.each_slice(2).to_a.each do |pair|
          headers_hash[pair.first] = pair.last unless headers_hash.keys.include? pair.first
        end
        return headers_hash
      end

      def process_times
        times = Process.times
        return ProcessTimes.new((times.utime * 1_000_000).to_i,
          (times.stime * 1_000_000).to_i)
      end
    end

  end # module Utils
end # module PhusionPassenger
```

And then in 'config/application.rb' do:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
  require 'passenger_extension'
end
```

And then restart a webserver.

NOTICE: I'm not sure that this doesn't break any other functionality so use it on your own risk and please let me know if you find any harm from this approach.

Comment: Glad to help to someone else :)

Comment: hi, i tried to use your fix, but it doesn't work on Rails 4.2, do you know if there are some differences ?

Comment: hi @Léo, I didn't face this issue with 4.2. FYI here in my question I've been describing the debugging process with rails 3.2 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178033/rails-3-2-f-file-field-causes-routing-error. So, you can apply a similar approach to find out what goes wrong with rails 4.2

Comment: Didn't find... My passenger is 5.0.23 and now, `split_by_null_into_hash` is under PhusionPassenger::Utils::NativeSupportUtils but with your method it's not fixing the problem. I'm so sad @trushkevich

Comment: @Léo, check and let me know if this gist helps https://gist.github.com/trushkevich/cc5b87e3b6f440738441 (it's based on passenger 5.0.25). It's more like a guess as I can't reproduce the issue with passenger 5 and also I don't have enough time to test the solution well, but I checked (with Nginx) and can confirm that uploads at least work this way (without initially having the issue).

Comment: You saved my life thank you , it's working!! Update your answer maybe for all users who are with passenger 5. (Funny thing is that you asked your original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178033/rails-3-2-f-file-field-causes-routing-error) , exactly, 3 years ago ! 2march 2013)

Comment: @Léo, welcome. Indeed, funny thing about the "anniversary" :-) Sure, I'll update the answer (I've been waiting for a confirmation from you that it solves the issue with passenger 5).

Answer (score 0):

One issue here is you're not specifying whether the route is defined on the collection or a member. Which one of these is the correct route?

```
programs/:id/add_file

programs/add_file
```

You should construct your routes like this:

```
resources :programs do
  post 'add_file', :on => :member
end
```

or

```
resources :programs do
  member do
    post 'add_file'
  end
end
```

The above will take post requests at `programs/:id/add_file` and send them to `ProgramsController.add_file` with the `params[:id]` as the program id.

If you want this on the collection, you could do:

```
resources :programs do
  post 'add_file', :on => :collection
end
```

or

```
resources :programs do
  collection do
    post 'add_file'
  end
end
```

This would take post requests at `programs/add_file` and send them to `ProgramsController.add_file`, but no `params[:id]` would be set.

In general you should always specify whether routes are on the collection or member, and you should specify which verb a route should accept (ie use 'get' or 'post' etc. instead of 'match').

Try the above and see if that solves your problem, if not please let me know and I'll take another look.

Comment: That didn't seem to solve the problem. But thank you for differentiating Collection and Member, I was never clear on those. My routes file certainly needs cleanup.

The thing that is confusing me is my routes look correct when checking with Rake. The main issue seems to be part of the route disappearing. So:
/programs/223/add_file
becomes:
/223/add_file

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add

```
:via => [:post]
```

to your route specification.  It seems odd that it'd work on development and not on production, but as I understand rails routing, the matcher that you've added is only going to respond to get.

Try changing your match to

```
match "add_file" => "programs#add_file", :via => [:post]
```

Also, based on the answer just submitted by Andrew, you're probably better off using the member specifier to be explicit about the fact that the operation is happening on a particular Program with a particular id, and not the collection.  It also should save some code in your add_file method which is probably working hard to get the id parameter from the url.